# Cleaning the apt database

Tags: apt

It seems that now upgrades and installs are taking a long time. This seems mostly to be happening when reading the database. Is there a way of restructuring the database to make it more efficient?

Comment: You might try `aptitude clean`  but I am not sure it would speed up things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo apt-get clean` to clear your package cache. But what is the behaviour you are seeing?

Does it stop at a particular point?